# VS code Shows BrokenImport While importing a Package in golang?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

i have an issue in VS code while importing a package.VS code shows could not find the Package in GOBIN or GOROOT.But the program runs fine.But the issue is when this Problem arise the intellisense stops working to make it work i need to manually update gopls everytime when i import a package[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrph0.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Make sure to use modules.

Answer (score -1):

In VS Code try these steps:

1. `ctrl + shift + p`
2. Type `Go`
3. `Install/Update tools`

Should solve most of such cases.

Comment: i usually do this but the problem is i need to do this manually everytime when i import a package